# Suitable Cloud for Uploading PDF along with react native and mern stack

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, react-native, google-cloud-storage

I have used cloudinary to upload images and videos for my project and using google drive has been restricted for me so can you suggest me some other cloud where I can store the pdf and use the uri to access it in mongo database.

Comment: I would suggest Google Cloud Storage. Using [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) you will be able to upload and downloads you files. Also check the pricing list for the [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Comment: Thanks man for the recommendation.. I will surely look into it.